# ViewBag - Object reference not found - MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, null, viewbag

Upon publishing my MVC 3 Web Application to my website I get an error stating an Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The 'error' line is:
Line 2:      `ViewBag.Title = "Index";`

This is my Index view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

This is my Home Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

I have uploaded DLL's:

```
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you look in /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml, you will probably see something like this:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```

It is assuming this property has been set somewhere. Usually, you set this in your child views. So the easiest solution is to modify your Index.cshtml view so that it resembles something like this:

```
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Title of the page";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have made the changes as you suggested but now I am getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on the 'Layout =' part. Should I be using WebPages 1.0.0.0 or WebPages 2.0.0.0 I uploaded the WebPages 2.0.0.0 dll

Comment: When you look at the properties of the System.Web.WebPages reference in your project in Visual Studio it will tell you which version you need. If you need more help with "bin deploying" your MVC 3 application, you can have a look at this guide: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I should be using WebPages 1.0.0.0, how do I upgrade to version 2.0.0.0?

Comment: I don't think you should. Just upload the assemblies from the blogpost.

Comment: Well I uploaded WebPages 1.0.0.0 instead of the version 2 and my website now works, should I be changing the version to 2.0.0.0 in both Web.config files to use WebPages 2.0.0.0 ?

Comment: I don't see a reason to do so.

Answer (score 14):

I hit the same ViewBag error. 
in my case Model was null but the exception was directing to viewbag row.

When I passed a model to view error fixed.

Comment: My Model was null but exception was redirecting to ViewBag. Strange! But Your solution worked. Thank You.

Comment: I had a similar issue. An entity in the model was empty/null. tried passing the name of the entity to another ImageHelper function and got the viewbag error. Weird. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please ensure that layout (_Layout.cshtml) is present inside Views folder. cshtmls/aspx inside the Views folder only inherit the ViewBag property.

~ Z